# Variations : Anti-Symmetric Relations on an $n$-Element Set : Graph Theoretic Elucidation

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, equivalence-relations, algebraic-graph-theory

---

Question:

> How many antisymmetric relations are there on an $n$-element set?

---

Guess:

I suspect that there are $2^n$ such relations.

---

Discussion:

I'm told that anti-symmetric relations on a set with $n$ elements can be seen as directed subgraphs, perhaps also called a diagraph, of a complete graph with $n$ vertices. Would anyone here be willing to pictorially represent what is being said here using the example where $n=3$?

---

Thoughts:

What I think the first answerer is trying to say is that any pair of points amongst $n$ points can be connected by a directed arrow which represents that $aRb$ holds. A line between any two distinct pairs could then be seen as the instance of when $aRb$ and $bRa$, which can occur in exactly $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ ways. Thus, for each "line" one has a binary choice, namely $1:=$ true or $0:=$ false. Therefore, there are exactly $2^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$ variations.

---

[image]

---

Comment: I may be mislead here...

Comment: @dtldarek What do the straight lines mean? I mean, "---" instead of "$\rightarrow$".

Comment: It means that it's late and I need sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

$2^n\cdot 3^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$ possible outcomes exist, right? $\leftarrow$ Please check...

---

A relation is anti-symmetric when the following holds:
$$\forall~a,b\in X,~aRb~\wedge~bRa\implies a=b$$
Now, it is interesting to note that antisymmetry on an $n$-element set can be viewed as a directed subgraph of a complete graph; that is, subgraphs of a complete graph where every edge $e$ has an orientation:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image http://sophia-blackbook.com/resources/complete_graphs.JPG](http://sophia-blackbook.com/resources/complete_graphs.JPG)

The complete graph $K_n$ has $n$ vertices and exactly $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ edges, so for each edge we have three choices, namely if a directed arrow points from $a$ to $b$, from $b$ to $a$, or no arrow whatsoever, where an arrow between pairs of points in the set connotes that an anti-symmetric relation holds between them. Now, this would then mean that there are precisely $3^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$ many variants, as there are $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ edges for $K_n$; however, we are forgetting that $a$ can be related to itself, so for each such variation there are exactly $2^n$ variations, namely whether $a$ is related to itself or not. Hence, there are
$$3^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}\cdot 2^n$$
total outcomes for such demands.

---

Comment: I'm still unsure (07/22/2013).

Comment: Yes, this is correct; you should feel free to accept it.

Comment: +1 A well deserved upvote $\ddot\smile$ Although it seems I wasn't of much help, I'm glad you have learned something about graphs (judging from the previous comments) – a generous reward for drawing those 27 triangles $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

- Any antisymmetric relation on $n$-element set can be viewed as a directed subgraph of a complete graph $K_n$.
- Complete graph $K_n$ has $\binom{n}{2}$ edges.
- Each edge can be directed (independently) in 2 ways (and of course, there might not be an edge).
- Finally, there are $2^n$ choices for different $x$es in $R(x,x)$.

I hope this helps ;-)

**Edit:** pointed out explicitly reflexivity choices.

**Edit:** As you wished, a diagram for $n = 3$. Please note that the loops $R(x,x)$ were not pictured, and as such there are in fact $2^3 = 8$ times as many cases as in the following figure:

[image: antisymmetric]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the terms. Perhaps you are good explaining things.

Comment: I suspected something like this was the case...

Comment: From *Proofs from the Book* I get that a directed graph is a "[graph] where every edge $e$ has an orientation," but what is orientation?

Comment: Take any two distinct elements $a$ and $b$. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ such pairs. For each such pair you have three choices: $a \leq b$, $b \leq a$ or $a \not\leq b \land b \not\leq a$.

Comment: How can you get the last choice?

Comment: What does "directed" mean?

Comment: Actually, there is a forth choice: $a\leq b\wedge b\leq a$.

Comment: @Tomas, that would mean that $a = b$.

Comment: I mean how can you get $a\not\leq b \wedge b\not\leq a$?

Comment: @Trancot For example, an empty relation is antisymmetric.

Comment: @dtldarek: Oops, I didn't get the _anti_.

Comment: What do you mean Tomas?

Comment: @dtldarek So each arrow's direction represents what then?

Comment: Perhaps you are industrious enough to give visual example for a set with $n=3$ elements.

Comment: @Trancot Antisymmetry is something like "for every two distinct elements, you can have arrow pointing in only one direction". Of course, there might be no arrow at all. I put an arrow from $a$ to $b$ if $R(a,b)$.

Comment: This $R$ is an antisymmetric $R$, correct?

Comment: @dtldarke See my most recent edit.

Comment: @Trancot See my most recent edit ;-)

Comment: dtldarek: What did you use to compute the graphs? Just curious ;-)

Comment: @amWhy This time keyboard and [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape). When facing large quantities I use some scripting language like [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) to render diagrams into [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

Comment: Nice work! (Thanks for the link!) + 1